# No funciona el path relativo al fuente

Tags: python, rutas

acaba de empezar con Python y mientras hago unos ejercicios me encuentro que de un día para otro mi código no sirve ya que ahora necesito escribir el path completo:

Mis ficheros, el fuente y el ico siguen estando en “c:\python\Example.py” y “c:\python\yo.ico” y mi código que funcionó:

```py
from tkinter import *

Ventana = Tk()
Ventana.title('Test Grafico')
Ventana.iconbitmap('yo.ico')
```

Ahora necesito escribir:

```
Ventana.iconbitmap('c:\python\yo.ico')
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hola. Sería bueno que colocaras el stack del error para endender mejor tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

La función `Tk.iconbitmap` funciona inesperadamente mal en algunos sistemas.

Prueba a reemplazarla por la siguiente llamada a *Tcl/Tk* y así poder continuar usando un *path relativo*:

`Ventana.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', Ventana._w, PhotoImage(file='yo.ico'))`

Desconozco el motivo, pero mientras que algunos de mis programas funcionan correctamente en *Windows 7* necesito aplicar esta modificación en *Kubuntu 18.04* para poder cargar el *icono*.